# How to avoid an attribute error when double-inheriting a TestCase class in python unittest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance

I have the following construct, in which I derive a class from `unittest.TestCase`, in which a method is called that is defined in the actual test class `MyTests`.

```
import unittest

class TestCase1(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):  
        print cls.extra()

class TestCase2(TestCase1):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        TestCase1.setUpClass()

class MyTests(TestCase1):

    @classmethod
    def extra(cls):
        return 42

    def test1(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The above code, as it stands, works as expected. When I execute the tests, the `setUpClass` of `TestCase1` is run, which executed `extra()` defined in `MyTests`.

The problem comes into play when I want to use `TestCase2` instead `TestCase1`, i.e. when I change the '1' to '2' in the following line:

```
class MyTests(TestCase2): # using TestCase2 instead
```

The idea is that `setUpClass` of `TestCase2` is called, which in itself calls `setUpClass` from the basic class, i.e. `TestCase1`, which executes the method `extra`. However, I get an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'TestCase1' has no attribute 'extra'
```

I seem to misunderstand some concepts here. I would have expected my code to work in both cases (maybe there is some error), or to fail in both cases. Any ideas what here might be wrong or how I can fix the problem are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend using [super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-and-init-methods) instead of `TestCase1.setUpClass()`.

Comment: Tried this, it doesn't print 42

Comment: Sorry, maybe i had something wrong, it worked once I tried it again. :/

Answer (score 2):

The reason why is that when it is inheriting from `TestCase2` the `cls` passed to when `TestCase1.setUpClass()` is called is of the type `TestCase1`, which has no `extra()` method. When called from MyTests, it `cls` is an instance of `MyTests` which has an extra method.

`super` passes the `cls` parameter from `MyTests.setUpClass(cls)` to `TestCase1.setUpClass(cls)`. So when it reaches `TestCase1`, `cls` has an `extra()` method.